# ASP.NET register a control from external dll on a page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am banging my head against the brick wall today.  I am porting a site I had developed on an old box across to a new dev env.  I have not just copied all the files as I didn't have a great file structure and some parts of the code needed to be removed as I went along.

Originally I had created a website (File -> New -> Web Site).  I wanted a file structure something like:

[Popular folder structure for build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446017/popular-folder-structure-for-build)

So I created a new blank solution so the sln file was on its own, then added projects (various DLL projects) and am ASP.NET Web Application.

This last part seems to have caused me a few issues that have given me a headache.  As far as I understand (this could be a little limited), a website (as I first had) is different to the later type I created.  For example the App_Code folder part didn't work as before.  To solve that I created a separate DLL for the webLibrary cs files and added a reference to it.

My problem now is how I register this on a page to be able to use the controls in it.  For example I have a control that inherits from TextBox, when it was in the App_Code folder I could use:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="sarg" Namespace="MyNameSpace" %>
```

Then use

```
<sarg:SARGTextBox id="clienttitletxtbox" runat="server" OnTextChanged="textboxfiltering_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></sarg:SARGTextBox>
```

Now it is in its own DLL and namespace I can not figure out how to get it to work, I just keep getting warnings saying "Cannot resolve symbol 'SARGTextBox'".

It is probably really simple but I can no longer see the wood for the trees.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you both, you are both right, I like the web.config solution more as I only have to do it once.  Main problem turned out to be ME! shock horror, a user error!  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have created a WebApplication instead of Website. WebApplication does not support App_Code.

1. Add your ClassLibrary as a reference.
2. Then In web.config register your control.

```
    <pages>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="myctl" namespace="Namespace.ClassName" assembly="AssemblyName"/>
        </controls>
    </pages>
```

3. Rebuild your solution.
4. Open the page and find your control from Toolbox and drop it on your page,

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the assembly where your control is declared :

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="sarg" Namespace="MyNameSpace" Assembly="MyLibrary" %>
```