# error type or namespace name profilecommon could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I compile this code, It show me this kind of error type or namespace name profilecommon could not be found. Could someone help me how to solve this?

```
case "Profile":
ProfileCommon pc = Profile.GetProfile(user.UserName);
DropDownList3.Items.Clear();
foreach (SettingsProperty p in
ProfileCommon.Properties)
{
DropDownList3.Items.Add(p.Name);
}
MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 4;
break;
}
```

Comment: If someone know please help me? It is very important

Answer (score 0):

You are likely missing a `using` statement or assembly reference to the namespace/assembly that contains `ProfileCommon`. Check your references!

**Edit:**

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584507/web-application-project-how-to-use-profilecommon) question for a possible solution to your issue.

Comment: which reference I should check? System.Web.dll or another?

Comment: It seems that `ProfileCommon` is in the `System.Web.Profile` namespace, so yes, try referencing the `System.Web.dll` assembly file.

Comment: I add this reference but still this problem? Should I change something in web.config or another place?

Comment: I edited my answer to include a reference to another question that may help you resolve your issue.